# A java Socket is a TCP socket. Do I send TCP header information to a website?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, ip

I am working on an Android app that uses VpnService to receive all packets coming from the interface (IP packets).

Once I receive a packet, I look at the IP header to check the protocolm source IP, destination IP. If its TCP, then I look at the TCP header, take the port numbers and try to send the packet to the destination IP.

My question is, do I have to strip away the IP and TCP headers when sending the data through a Socket() in java? Or do I leave the TCP header intact?

For more information, I count the offset from both IP and TCP headers so that I send the data right after the headers are finished. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. In android, there is a new Service called VpnService that routes all traffic through to my application. The byte data that comes is from the IP layer. I simply want to reroute the data back to the destination through an outside socket. So far I do this by unpacking the IP header (IpV4) and grabbing source IP, destination IP, protocol and header length. IF it is a TCP protocol, I then unwrap the TCP header to grab the destination and source ports as well as the offset for the TCP header. Anything after that I am guessing is data to be sent through the socket?

Comment: How are you doing this? Using raw sockets somehow with JNI? Or just plain java.net.Socket?

Comment: I tried plain socket, but it was not connecting. It was probably because somehow I could not protect the socket from the VpnService. The VpnService has a protect() method that protects it from being re-directed. So then I tried using a blocking SocketChannel. It gets protected ok and it connects ok, but the traffic doesn't seem to get sent through because while I'm running the VpnService, I am not able to use the Chrome browser on my tablet.

Comment: There's no difference for this purpose between Socket and SocketChannel. If you're using either of them you are only concerned with the data payload, not the IP or TCP headers.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know. I was told this, but I wanted to verify it 100%. Please write it as an answer and I will mark it answered.

Comment: Also if don't mind answering another question for me. When I get the payload I try to search for "GET" in hex values (0x47,0x45,0x54) to find the HTTP header, but I never find one. Is this right? I check the IP address requested and its asking for google.com. One thing though is that the port is 443 which means encrypted connection, so I was thinking this is probably why I can't find the Http header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to strip away the IP and TCP headers when sending the data through a Socket() in java? Or do I leave the TCP header intact?

You don't *have* the TCP header to strip. You just send and receive data.

> I tried plain socket, but it was not connecting ... So then I tried using a blocking SocketChannel

There's no difference for this purpose between Socket and SocketChannel. If you're using either of them you are only concerned with the data payload, not the IP or TCP headers.

> Also if don't mind answering another question for me. When I get the payload I try to search for "GET" in hex values (0x47,0x45,0x54) to find the HTTP header, but I never find one. Is this right? I check the IP address requested and its asking for google.com. One thing though is that the port is 443 which means encrypted connection, so I was thinking this is probably why I can't find the Http header.

That's correct. It's encrypted so you can't read it. But if you're writing an HTTP proxy, as you seem to be, all that should be preceded by a CONNECT command line in plain text, which you can get the target from.